# Assign different and specific subfolder to each Member with Assets

Tags: assets, custom-fields, file-uploads

i've to assign a subfolder to each member so when "User1" uses the Assets field to upload his photo, this is stored in a subfolder "main_upload_folder/user1_subfolder/". 
When "User2" uses the Assets field to upload his photo, this is stored in a subfolder "main_upload_folder/user2_subfolder/"

And this for each member, so when user upload a photo other users can't see other's member photo.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

This is the exact reason why I choose Channel Images in this case. With Channel Images you can choose if a user can see the stored images and if so, you can choose to show all or only the users images.

Also, if a user deletes the entry, the image will be deleted as well (which is also a hazard I experienced, not sure if this can be set)

Answer (score 0):

Alessio,

This is not possible with the current version of Assets.  It is something that we may consider for a future Assets version - but no guarantees right now.

-Lisa